# retrieving integer value from spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

i have two spiners, the first spinner is an Integer array and second is an array of 2D strings.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter1,adapter3;
String selectedsection;
Integer selectedsem;
Integer[] semester= new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
String[][] subject=new String[][]{{"m1"},{"m2"},{"m3"},{"m4"},{"m5"},{"m6"},{"m7"},{"m8"}};
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, semester);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    sp1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedsem = (Integer)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(selectedsem),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
    });

adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subject[selectedsem]);
    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    sp3.setAdapter(adapter3);
    sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedsubject = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(selectedsem),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedsubject, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
    });
```

the app crashes because it cannot find the value of `selectedsem`. SO, how to get the value of `selectedsem` from first spinner use it in second spinner.
Hope the question is understood!

Comment: Please add logcat

Comment: logcat says NullPointerException at this line-           adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subject[selectedsem]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is since it's Integer it can be null and you are trying to use it while initializing it and nothing is yet selected you may get nullpointerexception so better give it a default value of 0 or something at initialization

and then just create adapter for second spinner after the user selects the item.

You can place your second adapter creation just under onItemSelected

```
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectedsem = semester[parent.getSelectedItemPosition()];
        //second adapter code goes here
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNew = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subject[selectedsem]);
       sp3.setAdapter(adapterNew);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(selectedsem),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
});
```

we are just updating the second spinner just after the user selects some value in(OnItemSelected) the first spinner.

Comment: i tried both these ways but none worked.....if we initialise it with say 0, then after selecting from first spinner it's values doesn't gets updated

Comment: we can't create an Adapter inside `OnItemSelectedListener` method, it shows an error

Comment: just add this in inside the onItemSelected listener YourActivity.this instead of this only and do both things default value + adapter creation see my updated answer.

Comment: you can create adapter just resolve the error of first parameter by replacing this to YourActivity.this

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the second adapter in another  function and call it right after the first adapter made, I mean try to schedule the two task not asynchronous not asynchronous

Comment: i just tried...but its not working the value of `selectedsem` is null each time and does not gets updated

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the method `onItemSelected` of your first spinner's `OnItemSelectedListener` is **only called when the spinner actually gets selected by user**. So, when you try to instantiate your `adapter3`, `selectedsem` is still null. To fix this, you have to put all the code where you expect `selectedsem` to have a value, right after it actually **gets** a value, that is: inside `onItemSelected` method. Like this:

```
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedsem = (Integer)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(selectedsem),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (selectedsem != null) {
                adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subject[selectedsem]);     
                adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                sp3.setAdapter(adapter3);
                sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        selectedsubject = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(selectedsem),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedsubject, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
                });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: no you can't put this line `adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subject[selectedsem]);` inside onItemSelectedListener

Comment: To do this you also have to change your "this" to `YourActivity.this`